# Preload assocation with scope and argument in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-activerecord

Assuming we have something like this:

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :have_more_than_X_posts, -> (x) { where('posts_count > ?', x) }
end
```

I want to be able to call something like this: `Group.includes(users: {have_more_than_X_posts: 10})`

Ideas?

Comment: You can do it like this, `Group.includes(users).have_more_than_X_posts(x)`. [Check this out](http://blog.arkency.com/2013/12/rails4-preloading/)

Comment: Sorry it should be `:users` and not `users`.

Comment: Yes, I meant `undefined method have_more_than_X_posts for Group`

Comment: Then, the query can be like this: `Group.includes(:users).where('users.posts_count > ?', 10)`.

Comment: It wasn't quite an answer to my question, but it gave me an idea, based on your comment, which solved problem. Add it as an answer and i'll accept it. (And also, add `.references(:users)` because it will raise missing FROM clause.)

Comment: You can add this as an answer, as you figured it out. :)